# PendingIntent fails when target API was upgraded from Android 10 to Android 12

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have an old android app that worked well with API 29 as a target.

Now I updated the target to API 31 (Android 12) and the test on an Android 12 phone fails as soon as I try to get the "PendingIntent":

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(),myRequestCode,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

I double checked some resources on the web but I cannot find a hint why this fails.

What can I do to narrow down the possible causes?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent)?

Comment: Wasn't aware of the IMMUTABLE flag  - thanks for putting me on the right track!